# How save state of checkbox? if is enabled or disabled

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, state

I'm making an app that have a lot of checkbox. I wanted save the states of these but only could save if these are checked, but now I want save if is enabled or disabled,  since some checkbox active states to other checkbox. How can i do that?

...

```
if (view.equals(contador11)){
                if(contador11.isChecked()){
                    contador14.setEnabled(true);                
                }else{
                    contador14.setEnabled(false);               
                }
            }


        if (view.equals(contador12)){
            if(contador12.isChecked()){
                contador13.setEnabled(true);
                contador26.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                contador13.setEnabled(false);
                contador26.setEnabled(false);
                 }
        }


        if (view.equals(contador7)){
            if(contador7.isChecked()){
                contador15.setEnabled(true);                
            }else{
                contador15.setEnabled(false);               
            }
        }
```

...

Comment: You can save data to a SQLite database, `SharedPreferences`, or any other sort of file.

Comment: Yes, I thought in sharedPreferences, but I have a lot of checkbox and I want to know if there're a way with short code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your code exactly, but assuming you want to save all of them at the same time, you could save code by just putting them in a list or something. Here's an example.

---

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private CheckBox[] contadors;
private CheckBox contador1, contador2, contador3, contador4, contador5, contador6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    contador1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contador1);
    contador2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contador2);
    contador3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contador3);
    contador4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contador4);
    contador5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contador5);
    contador6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contador6);
}

public void clickContador(View view) { // Just for testing
    CheckBox contador = (CheckBox) view;
    view.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveContadors();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    contadors = new CheckBox[]{contador1, contador2, contador3, contador4, contador5, contador6};
    loadContadors();
}

private void saveContadors() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    for (int i = 0; i < contadors.length; i++)
        editor.putBoolean("contador" + i, contadors[i].isEnabled());
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadContadors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < contadors.length; i++)
        contadors[i].setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("contador" + i, true));
}
```

---

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/contador1"
    android:onClick="clickContador"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I have an array of checkbox (private CheckBox contador[]={contador0, contador1,...) and array of ints (private  int[] idArrayContador = {R.id.contador0, R.id.contador1,...). I want to save if the checkbox is enabled or not (I already saved if checkbox ischecked). I try it with some changes, but doesn't work. :/

Comment: I updated my code. What problem are you having exactly? Are you calling the `save` and `load` methods in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`?

Comment: I tried this code, but doesn't work. But I can't use "Checkbox[] contadors={R.id..." It gives error. I use the code that I wrote in the last comment and the rest of the code that you give me. I want to save the state of the checkboxes: enabled or disabled.

Comment: Did you test it? I am testing your code, but still doesn't save the state. It's always disabled. Anyway, thanks for your time. Tomorrow I'll try again.

Comment: `prefs.getBoolean()` takes a default argument for when the property doesn't exist. I set it to `false`, but it would make more sense for them to be enabled at first, I guess. I updated my code again. Check the `loadContadors ()` method. I tested it myself and it works even after destroying the app.

Comment: Sorry, but still does not work for me. I can check the box, but then it doesn't let me. What I want is to save the state, either enabled or disabled. Something like this (in onclick method): public void clickContador(View view) { 
    if(view.equals(contador5)){
     contador1.setEnabled(true);
     contador2.setEnabled(true);} assuming that it is deactivates in first instance. Anyway thanks! I'll keep trying.

Comment: My `clickContador()` method was just for demonstration. You shouldn't use it. `saveContadors()` and `loadContadors()` save the states of the checkboxes as you asked in your question. You just need to fit them in appropriately with your existing code.

Comment: Yes I know. The problem is that I'm testing your code only, but doesn't do that I need. When I close and then open again, the code becomes like the first time, is not saved. :/ Work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73482/discussion-between-pablo-villar-and-jimeux).

Answer (score 0):

To put the state of your `CheckBox`, we can use `SharedPreferences`:

```
CheckBox contador = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.contador1);
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();

if (contador.isChecked()) {
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("key", true).commit(); // put true value
}else{
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("key", false).commit(); // put false value
}
```

To get the value you saved back:

```
boolean myContador = prefs.getBoolean("key", false);
if (myContador == true) {
    // do your thing
}else{
    // the value is false, do something
}
```

Comment: I kept the state in this way, but just tell me if  is checked or not. And I want to do is save if is enabled or disabled.